# About the system in vc

Tags: c++

I run below code in vc.

```
 system("@echo off");
 system("set a=3");
 system("echo %a%");
 system("pause");
```

but it display as '%a%', but I require display as '3'.

How Can I make it? 
Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the "tmp.bat" file:

```
@echo off
set a=3
echo %a%
pause
```

and then call the

```
system("cmd /c tmp.bat")
```

The thing is that system() call creates a "clean" environment where the "a" variable has not been set (in the "echo %a%" call).

To convert the sequence of commands into something "executable" one might use some special tool, not the "VC".

Look for http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/  and similar tools.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Do you have any other ideas? I would like the bat file are invisible. And if I create a 'tmp.bat' file that will make bat file can seen by others.

Comment: Yes, you can create the Win32 Process and create the environment variables specifically for this Process (envp in main). For any further ideas you just have to specify what exactly are you trying to do.

Comment: I just want to make a program that covert '*.bat' file to '*.exe' file. At first I simply think I just need to use system("XXX"); "XXX" is stand for the every line in bat file. But I was wrong when the bat file set variable. Do you have any ideas that I can do this? Thank your very much.

Comment: Added the idea for you at the end of my answer.

Comment: I mean that such programs already exist. So when you ask how to make one I just suggest to use the existing one.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. But I want to create it by myself. Do you have any ideas on my trouble? or give me some link? Thanks very much.

Comment: The way I went through (pretty obvious, but really tough for a one-day project): write simple virtual machine and a compiler. Then write a stub program which executes the byte-code written at its end. Think it over: do you really need this ? Or do you need to something specific ?

Comment: By the way, some older versions of AutoIt contain actual source code - see for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

For a start, every single one of those commands runs independently of the other. By the time you try to echo `%a%`, the `set` for it (from the previous call to `system`) has been long forgotten. So, it's effectively the same as if you had opened up a brand new `cmd` window and typed:

```
Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]
(C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.

C:\Documents and Settings\Pax> echo %a%
%a%

C:\Documents and Settings\Pax> _
```

You will probably need to place all those instructions into a single `cmd` file then run:

```
system ("cmd /c c:\\full\\path\\to\my\\script.cmd");
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Do you have any other ideas? I would like the bat file are invisible. And if I create a 'tmp.bat' file that will make bat file can seen by others.

Comment: @iamlucker: yes, create it using permissions. Windows has long had the ability to protect files from other users.

Comment: How to create it with permissions? can you give me an example? thanks very much.

Comment: @iamlucker, _this_ question was what the problem was with your immediate code and how to make it so that that cmd file run as a single unit. If you want to ask a question about how to create files under Windows with permissions, that is a totally _different_ question despite it being related to your same problem, and you'll get a better spread of answers if you ask it as a question rather than in a comment.